# How cdo I builda tzutalin dlib library in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, android-native-library

I can use "[tzutalin dlib](https://github.com/tzutalin/dlib-android)" library for face detection used in Eclipse, but I don't know how to build a native library. Can any one help me?

I have used all classes which are required but I always get an error popup,and always so error in for `VisionDetRet ret : new PeopleDet().detBitmapFace();` method.